# Multiple instances of Featured Image Query

Tags: wp-query, permalinks, query-posts, post-thumbnails

I have some custom code built into the header of my theme that gets the featured image from a post, displays the image and links to the posts permalink when clicked on by a user.

The problem I am having is that I have this happening on 2 different divs pulling in info from 2 different categories, but when you hover over the link as a user, it uses the permalink from only one of the two images. I am using the "page links to" plugin to redirect the post to a page in the site, so I wonder if this is causing an issue. Below is my snippet getting the featured image in 2 separate divs:

```
<div id="homeprint">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=100' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
endwhile; ?>
</a>           
</div>

<div id="lookup">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=101' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</a>         
        </div>
```

Do I need to have two references of `wp_reset_postdata();` or am I just doing this wrong?

The example is [here](http://thurstonenergy.org) in the header. You'll see two rectangular images that should link to two different pages. Right now they both link to the same location. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the topmost images to the right of the logo? They link to different pages right now (although links seem to be reversed for what images say).

Comment: Yes, the top 2 images. They are reversed and I can't figure that part out either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both loops move

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

To after

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

`the_permalink()` is template tag and as such generates what it does, based on global `$post` variable. In your custom loop it doesn't contain the post you want until after `$the_query->the_post()` call.

Comment: Thanks Rarst, but I am getting syntax errors after moving to after the 'while' line.

Comment: @diventato well, you need to adjust things accordingly, probably by closing and opening PHP tags `?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction as I am doing just that :) I know now that I cannot call a permalink like that until after I tell it what to query.

Answer (score 0):

After some pointers from my homie Rarst, I was able to make this work. I changed

this

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=100' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
endwhile; ?>
</a>
```

to this

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=100' ); ?>

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
endwhile; ?>
</a>  
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

As Rarst mentioned, the permalink wasn't doing as it should due to the fact that it was not placed inside the loop and after the post query. After the query was called, the permalink had a place to link to... the post thumbnail.

I'm still experimenting with php even though I've been creating Wordpress-driven sites for years now. There is always something to learn in the wonderful world of web design :)